# NullPointerException - can't figure out what's null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have the following code that creates some views dynamically:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.tag_table_row, null); //this is the template for each view

            // set xyz dynamically
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.xyz); //id within the layout 
            textView.setText(xyz[i]);
            //set score dynamically
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.score);
            textView2.setText(scores[i]);
            //set bar graph dynamically
            TagBar tagBar = (TagBar) findViewById(R.id.tagbar);
            double tag1score = Double.parseDouble(scores[i]);
            Log.i("score", scores[i]);
            double factor = 250;
            double len = tag1score*factor;
            int length = (int) len;
            Log.i("length", Integer.toString(length));
            tagBar.setBarLength(length);                

            // insert into main view
            View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.tagTable);
            ((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(v, i, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }
```

`TagBar` is a class I created that basically draws a horizontal bar with a length that is determined by the "score".  All of this code works fine, except for the line `tagBar.setBarLength(length);`.  When this line runs, I get a `NullPointerException` and the app crashes.

As far as I know, `length` is defined and is not null, `tagBar` is defined and is not null, and the `setBarLength()` method is defined within the `TagBar` class.  Why am I getting a NullPointerException`?

`setBarLength()` is defined in the `TagBar` class like so:

```
    public void setBarLength(int n) {
    barLeng = n;
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}
```

Here's my Logcat:

```
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tforan.blobtag4/com.tforan.blobtag4.PlaceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1852)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1873)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4358)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at com.tforan.blobtag4.PlaceActivity.onCreate(PlaceActivity.java:169)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
07-20 12:33:52.029: E/AndroidRuntime(8075):     ... 11 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you include more of your code? Possibly your entire onCreate method. It happens within onCreate, but your for statement doesn't contain enough code to debug the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A null pointer exception is generated when you dereference a null pointer-  when something to the left of a . is null.  So the only thing that could cause it is tagbar being null, assuming you have the right line.  I'd make sure that the id you're searching for is actually in your xml.  If it really is, then I'd run it under a debugger.

Edit:  did you mean to search for the tagbar in the activity's view, rather than in the view you inflate in the loop?  That seems likely to be the bug.  All the other finds are v.findViewById, this one is just findViewById.

Comment: great catch.  that's exactly what it was.  changed to "TagBar tagBar = (TagBar) v.findViewById(R.id.tagbar);"  and it worked.  thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

check **here** `TagBar tagBar = (TagBar) findViewById(R.id.tagbar);`

you are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

because your `tagBar` object is null !